# 3 unknown, 3 nonlinear equations of form $xy - z =$ constant

Tags: nonlinear-system

How can I solve:     $$xy - z = a $$
                      $$xz - y = b $$
                     $$ yz - x = c $$ 
         for $x, y, z$ (where $a,b,c$ are constants)?   Let all variables and constants be integers 
         (or at least rational)

Answer (score 0):

The brute force method would be to isolate (“solve for”) $z$ in the third equation (assuming $y \neq 0$), and substitute into the first two.  That gives two nonlinear equations in two variables $x$ and $y$.  Then repeat: isolate either $y$ or $x$ in one of those new equations, and substitute into the other.  That should result in one (probably nonlinear) equation for one of the variables.